# Absorption phenomenon

Tags: material-science, optical-materials

Is Jablonski diagram in between valence and conduction bands (band gap or maybe virtual energy state)?  and what is specific material for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that for the Jablonski and the band diagram, the target size and emission process are difference.

Jablonski diagram is for the emission process at molecule. The luminescence occurs by the transitions between electronic states. This follows to the Jablonski diagram. Molecul of ground state (S0) is excited to the excited state by the absorption of eneagy. When spins of Highest Occupied Molecular Orbital (HOMO) and Lowest Unoccupied Molecular Orbital (LUMO) is antiparallel, that is singlet excited state (S1). When the spins are parallel, that is triplet excited state (T1). The emissions by transition from S1 to S0 and from T1 to S0 are the fluorescence and phosphorescent, respectively.
This process occurs at a single molecule.

On the other hand, band diagram is for the recombination process of electron and hole at bulk semiconductor constructed with a lot of atoms. For semiconductor with valence and conduction band, the luminescence occurs by the recombination of electrons and holes. This follows to the band diagram. Electrons in the valence band are excited optically and electrically and those electrons move to the conduction band. At this time, holes are formed in the valence band, simultaneously. When those electrons in the conduction band loss the eneagy and drop to the valence band, light is emitted by recombinating electrons and holes.
This process occurs under the interaction with periodically arranged atoms.

Following figure shows the difference. Left and right image are Jablonski and band diagram, respectively.

I apologize my poor English.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 


It is almost clear for me, so in that figure was seen if Jablonski and band diagrams occur in same time, right? but which make me confused is the kind of  "matter".
Jablonski for (spin) molecule and band diagram for excited electron (in a material).
Sorry, can you explain this?

Comment: When many molecules are assembled, energy band is formed by the interaction of each molecule. For example, it's covalent bond. At this time, electron transition is follow to the band diagram. In the case of single molecule or week interaction between molecules, it follows to Jablonski diagram. And about reason that spin joins to the transition, when an electron move near an atomic nucleus, orbiting and rotational motion connect by the magnetic interaction. By this, it is easy to invert the spin, the spin joins to the transition. This is just my interpretation. So other opinion may be existing.